# Convert Microsoft .hlp to something else printable

Tags: conversion, help-files

Anyone know of a good (free) tool that will convert a .hlp file into something that is decently formatted for printing?  PDF would be great, but anything printable will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is something like this:

[HLP Converter](http://www.qweas.com/download/converters/document_converters/abc_amber_hlp_converter.htm)

It's free to try for 30 days, but not free forever. It looks like it will convert to PDF though.

Comment: Yeah, I just played with that and it worked well.  Still looking for free, though :)  Might go for this if nothing comes through.

Answer (score 2):

Winhelp is a dead format so tools are becoming scarce as vendors drop support but there are a few tools still around.

- Herdsoft makes a winhelp
  [converter](http://www.herdsoft.com/catalog/ehlp2rtf.html)
- There is an open source winhelp
  [decompiler](http://www.geocities.com/mwinterhoff/helpdeco.htm), which you could use
  to retrieve the original sources for
  the help file. I believe it outputs
  rtf files (among others)which you
  could open in a word processor.